# How to find the result of following matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-12&8
\end{pmatrix}$$
To find$$A^5-6A^4-3A^3+17A^2-A+19I_2$$

I cannot come up with a simple algorithm to solve the polynomial, and I did use NumPy to calculate the result, which turned out to be extremely large (like $a_{21}=2081253036$).
This problem appears in a math test so I don't think the result should be that huge. What is the right way to find the correct answer?

Comment: Is the question simply to find that Sum/Difference?

Comment: You can use $A^2=8A-12I$.

Comment: Also ```>>> arr=np.array([[0, 1],[-12,8]])
>>> ans=np.linalg.matrix_power(arr,5) - 6*np.linalg.matrix_power(arr, 4)-3*np.linalg.matrix_power(arr, 3)+17*np.linalg.matrix_power(arr,2)-arr+19*np.eye(2)
>>> ans
array([[  7.,  -5.],
       [ 60., -33.]])```, so you must have done something seriously wrong in numpy.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, you are right, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use CAYLEY HAMILTON theorem to get the characteristic equation of $A$ as
$A^2-8A+12I=0$.
Now note that $A^5−6A^4−3A^3+17A^2−A+19I2= (A^2-8A+12I)(A^3+2A^2+A+1) - 5A+7I2$ (due to polynomial division). Since $A^2-8A+12I=0$, we have $A^5−6A^4−3A^3+17A^2−A+19I2= 7I2 - 5A$, which is easy to calculate : )

Comment: This method is cool, thank you a lot.

Comment: @B.W.Zhang you're welcome. Note that sometimes the questions can be a bit tougher like find A^50. In those cases pattern observation and induction work really well (clearly polynomial division becomes infeasible there). Pattern observation means something like A^3= A or on some elements of A (often asked in JEE exam).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of matrix $A$ by solving $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, which gives $\lambda=2,6$, from where you can find out the eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$, such that $Av_1=2v_1, \ Av_2=6v_2$ by solving two pairs of simultaneous equations.

Then taking $v_1,v_2$ to be the columns of a $2\times 2$ matrix $Q$, you should have [$A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix), where $\Lambda = diag(2,6)$ is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal.

Finally, this helps because $A=Q\Lambda Q^{-1} \implies A^n = Q\Lambda^n Q^{-1}$.

P.S. Angina's comment emphasises the polynomial (in $\lambda$) you get when you put $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: I actually had tried this before posting the question, but it seemed still to take a lot of computation as 6^5 is a large number and $Q^{-1}$ consists of fractions. But thank you all the same for giving this suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Diagonalize A, i.e. find the matrix of eigenvectors such that $A=V^{-1}DV$, with D the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. Note that $A^n=V^{-1}D^nV$. $D^n$ is easy to calculate since it's diagonal. Now, rewrite the equation as

$V^{-1}(D^5-6D^4-3D^3+17D^2-D+19 I)V$

Should be easier